# git Second Order History

Tags: git, git-history-graph, git-history-rewrite

When working on a patchest, I'm expected to provide a set of clean commits. Therefore I often find myself rewriting history repeatedly before my commit-set is clean and ready to be merged.
In this process, after receiving comments from reviewers, I go back with `rebase -i` to fix my code, fix the commit messages etc. Each time a new revised commit is created to replace the previous one. The previous commit is still out there but is no longer part of the revised history.

After a few history-rewrite iterations I finally get a clean revised commit-set that I can push or convert to a patchset.
But now I sometimes like to go back and review the history of changes I did to a commit or set of commits and see what I have done in this history-rewrite process.
I could track it manually - write down somewhere the commit hash of every commit I'm editing before it's rewritten. That way I could review the history of history-rewrites, but this is tedious and error-prone.

Is there a way to automate this and let git itself track the "second order" history - the history of history-rewrites? Get a `git log'` for a commit that would show all the "amend" operations performed historically to generate that commit?

Comment: Does `git reflog` do what you want? It will show all changes to references, by whatever command you have run. I don't know if you can make it show only things referring to the history of a certain commit, but it seems hard.

Comment: @LeonardoDagnino git reflog can show the history of references such as HEAD or branch. I'm looking for the history of modifications of a commit, not of a reference so I'm not sure git reflog can help.

Answer (score -1):

There's no such thing as:

> the history of modifications of a commit

as commits themselves are literally unchangeable.  History rewriting doesn't change the old commits: instead, it makes new-and-improved commits, which you are now using *instead of* the old commits.

What you *can* do, to some extent, is to use the reflogs to find the hash IDs that various names (branch names for instance) *used to* claim as the most recent commit, and use `git rev-parse` to find the hash IDs they *now* claim.  Then use `git rev-list` or `git log` to find commits reachable from the current branch tips.

This has some rather strong limitations.  If you've always replaced old-and-lousy commits one-for-one with new-and-improved commits, it's easy to say that `branch~5` is the replacement for `branch@{1}~5` for instance.  But if your history rewrite ever adds or deletes a commit during the rewrite, there's no easy correspondence here.

The other thing you can do, depending on your history rewriting tools, is to keep a mapping file or database.  If you have a mapping that says "old commit hash H = new and improved hash H'", for every replaced commit, along with mappings such as "old hash H was deleted" or "new hash H is inserted between old hashes G and I" where appropriate, that will let you do what you want.

In general, however, this is an unsolvable problem.  Git *does* contain something called `git range-diff` that works on a different variant of the problem: it compares diffs of some known sets of commits—you'll need to save the start and end point hash IDs—and describes the difference between those diffs as "old patch 1 was modified to become new patch 3", "old patch 2 was deleted", "old patch 3 became old patch 1", "new patch 2 inserted", and so on.